# Any idea on optimizing for loops with multiple iteration in iOS app

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, optimization, xcode-instruments

I am doing the following calculation with **Wf1** of size 1024x3136. Is there any suggestion on how can the following be optimized?

```
    var temp2: Float = 0.0
    //
    var AFC1: [Float] = [Float](count: 1024, repeatedValue: Float())
    var BFC1: [Float] = [Float](count: 1024, repeatedValue: Float())
    //
    for i in 0..<1024{
        for j in 0..<64*49{
            temp2 += HP5flat[j] * Wf1[j][i]
        }
        AFC1[i] = temp2
        temp2 = 0
    }
```

The above calculation is taking almost of 46% of the performance. Here is a snapshot from the Instruments.[image: Bottleneck Snapshot]

Comment: Please read [ask]. Your title says absolutely nothing about what your question is about. The text provided is barely better.

Comment: Isn't it *good* that this line is accounting for most of the performance cost? It's the only line shown which does any meaningful computation.

Comment: I think text is self-explanatory. I have changed the title.

Comment: @jtbandes Yes, it's true that it's the line doing any meaningful computation. The whole computation accounts for ~1.5 seconds. I am trying to look for an optimization that can bring it down to minimum of .5 seconds.

Comment: Did you compile the code with optimization enabled? Have you considered using [Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/index.html) or [simd](http://www.russbishop.net/swift-2-simd)?

Comment: Yes, I am compiling the code with optimization enabled. No, I have never used them to a great extent. Could you suggest anything?

Comment: You might ensure that the memory layout for the 2D array  Wf1 is  [_row-major_](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/memory-layout-of-multi-dimensional-arrays/). I have no idea, how Swift does layout its 2D arrays, though. Additionally, you can parallelise the computation using `dispatch_apply`.

Comment: How would you use dispatch_apply on two iterations?